# Create legend in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, legend

How to create the color box like below based on the array list using JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: Why you down vote for this?

Comment: @Maninblack, because you are lazy.

Comment: You've shown no effort in solving your problem *and* your question is unclear. See [ask]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the array key as a box `id`, then use set the background color programmatically using the value pointed by that key on `colorList`.

Please run the snippet to know how it works.

```js
var colorList = {t1: 'red', t2: 'green', t3: 'blue'};

colorize = function(colorList) {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
  
    for (var key in colorList) {
        var boxContainer = document.createElement("DIV");
        var box = document.createElement("DIV");
        var label = document.createElement("SPAN");

        label.innerHTML = key;
        box.className = "box";
        box.style.backgroundColor = colorList[key];

        boxContainer.appendChild(box);
        boxContainer.appendChild(label);

        container.appendChild(boxContainer);

   }
}

colorize(colorList);
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

I hope that helps :D

Comment: Are you There friend?

Comment: @Maninblack please take a look now. It create all boxes inside the `container` and add the label too.

Comment: To add where? I don't understand :(

Comment: Try some like this : `var colorlist = {}; for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {  
  colorlist['t' + i] = 'my value ' + i; }`.